# Minimum usable screen width in mobile web application

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application. I want to know the minimum usable screen width that is recommended by best practises working group for a mobile web application.

I did search on this topic, but can't find out appropriate solution for this. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the supporting screens information provided here

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

you can see that even screens that fall into the 'small' profile are generally at least 320dp (dp stands for density pixel and translates to 240px for low density devices and 480px for higher density devices)

With that, I would suggest supporting at least 240px to be very safe, however the number of devices with this profile are somewhat low and I would think it would be OK to only support a width of at least 320px.

Comment: i have 4 options 100,120,140px and none of above.. ..Which one should i use ?

Comment: Why are you limited to only those options?